# :o autocomplete

Tags: autocompletion, normal-mode

Without any plugins, I am able to autocomplete `:vsp filena<tab>`

I wonder why I don't get autocompletion of filenames with `:o`. I have tried this in different installations, terminals and OS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`:o[pen]` comes from Vi. It's intended to support so called "open mode" which is no-op in Vim. You should use `:e[dit]` instead.